# CSS: how to have a 2x2 grid with images centered inside each cell and a div at the bottom right corner of each image

Tags: css, flexbox, css-grid

Basically I have two conflicting requirements for my template that I cannot find a solution for:

0. it's a 2x2 grid with 4 images, each image centered in its own cell,
1. the image sizes must shrink when the screen height gets too small, and
2. the letter 'O' div must stay at the bottom right corner of its image

I have spent a significant amount of time creating the minimum reproducible example below that is very well documented. I think the problem is best understood when reading the code and looking at the pictures. I think the easiest way to work with this would be to create two files inside of a folder on your Desktop and then open the index.html file in the browser while using the inspector tool settings that I am showing in the images below. But you can also view the Codepen [here](https://codepen.io/felix-olszewski/pen/gOqKbXg).

```css
.outermost-container {
  padding: 40px;
  height: calc(100vh - 80px);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-centering-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* without this the images would not shrink in size when the screen height decreases */
  overflow: hidden;
  /* but the height: 100% & width: 100% are also crucial for this to be the case */
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.relative-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* TODO: I have two requirements:
        1. the images should shrink in size when the screen height decreases
        2. the images should have the 'O'-div at the bottom right of their corner
    */
  /* THIS FULFILLS REQUIREMENT 1 */
  /*height: 100%;*/
  /*width: 100%;*/
  /* THIS FULFILLS REQUIREMENT 2 */
  position: relative;
  /* TODO FIXME:
        When having both snippets above commented in at same time,
        then ofc the 'O'-div is not at the bottom right of the image anymore,
        since the relative-wrapper is now full available width/height
        It is two conflicting requirements!
     */
}

.relative-div img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}

.relative-div div {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0">
  <div class="outermost-container">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="image-centering-div">
        <div class="relative-div">
          <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp2x/wp4471355.jpg" alt="">
          <div class="O-div">O</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-centering-div">
        <div class="relative-div">
          <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1699534956827-a02df22f4e3a?q=80&w=3540&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt="">
          <div class="O-div">O</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-centering-div">
        <div class="relative-div">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510505678115-f2a7ae4cfea9?q=80&w=1681&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt="">
          <div class="O-div">O</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="image-centering-div">
        <div class="relative-div">
          <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1661852207925-4f1d03556a2e?q=80&w=3540&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt="">
          <div class="O-div">O</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I viewed the code in my browser with those settings:

[image: good result when screen is high enough]

-> as you can see this is my desired result. And it works then the screen is high enough.

Now when you reduce the height the following happens:

[image: bad result 1]

-> as you can see requirement 1 of keeping the images fully visible is not satisfied (and actually neither is requirement 2, even when the o-div is at the bottom right corner of the images, it is not visible for some since for some of the images where the bot right corner is no longer visible)

this is what happens when I comment in the "REQUIREMENT 1 100% width/height styles":

[image]

-> requirement 1 is of keeping the images not clipped is satisfied. But the requirement 2 of keeping the o-div at the bottom right corner is not satisfied

Comment: hello, 2x2 would need a grid layout that can handle this, not flex IMOHO :)

Answer (score 2):

One possible approach is as follows, though I've taken the liberty of adjusting the HTML in an attempt to be a little more semantic. Explanatory comments are in the code, below:

```css
/* removing generic browser defaults for cross-browser
   similarity: */
*,::before,::after {
  /* causes the browser to use the same sizing algorithm for
     all elements, which includes the border-width and padding
     in the assigned sizes: */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  padding-block: 1rem;
}

.gallery {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, silver, black);
  display: grid;
  gap: 2rem;
  grid-template-areas:
    "one two"
    "three four";
  /* if the element is smaller than the inline-size of its
     parent, then we center on that inline axis: */
  margin-inline: auto;
  max-inline-size: 80vmin;
  padding: 1rem;
}

li {
  display: grid;
  
  /* the ampersand is required for Chromium-based browsers, who require that
     the first character of a nested selector (as I'm using here) is a symbol,
     in order to easily distinguish between a CSS property and a nested
     selector (Firefox allows use of the "relaxed" selector syntax): */
  
  & figure {
    display: grid;
    max-inline-size: 100%;
    /* centering the content both horizontally and vertically
       within the <figure> element, and causes the child(ren)
       to occupy the smallest possible size within the constraints
       of the applied CSS: */
    place-content: center;
  }
  
  & figure > * {
    /* all items are in the same grid-area within the parent,
       I suspect there's a shorter way to achieve this but I
       couldn't (quickly) find a way: */
    grid-area: 1 / 1 / 1 / 1;
  }
  
  & img {
    max-inline-size: 100%;
  }
  
  & figcaption {
    /* purely aesthetic and for visibility, adjust to taste */
    background-color: #fffa;
    mix-blend-mode: hard-light;
    /* places the figcaption at the end of both the
       inline and block axes: */
    place-self: end;
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- the content seems to be a list of images, hence the use of <ol>; I'm assuming it's meant to
     be in a particular order, so I used the <ol> element; if it's not required to be in
     that order then a <ul> is also an option: -->
<ol class="gallery">
  <!-- for reasons of HTML validity the content is wrapped in <li> elements: -->
  <li>
    <!-- using a figure element to contain the images, with related text wrapped in a
         <figcaption> element: -->
    <figure>
      <img src="//wallpapercave.com/dwp2x/wp4471355.jpg" alt="">
      <figcaption>text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="//plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1699534956827-a02df22f4e3a?q=80&amp;w=3540&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;ixlib=rb-4.0.3&amp;ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt="">
      <figcaption>text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="//images.unsplash.com/photo-1510505678115-f2a7ae4cfea9?q=80&amp;w=1681&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;ixlib=rb-4.0.3&amp;ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt="">
      <figcaption>text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
  <li>
    <figure>
      <img src="//plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1661852207925-4f1d03556a2e?q=80&amp;w=3540&amp;auto=format&amp;fit=crop&amp;ixlib=rb-4.0.3&amp;ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt="">
      <figcaption>text</figcaption>
    </figure>
  </li>
</ol>
```

[JS Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/dj84vxcp/4).

References:

- CSS:

  - [`background`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background).
  - [`background-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color).
  - [`box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing).
  - [`&` CSS nesting selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Nesting_selector).
  - [CSS nesting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting).
  - "[Using CSS Nesting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_nesting/Using_CSS_nesting)."
  - [`display`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).
  - [`gap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap).
  - [`grid-area`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-area).
  - [`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin).
  - [`margin-inline`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin-inline).
  - [`max-inline-size`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-inline-size).
  - [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width).
  - [`mix-blend-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mix-blend-mode).
  - [`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding).
  - [`place-content`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-content).
  - [`place-self`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-self).
- HTML:

  - [`<figure>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure/).
  - [`<figcaption>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figcaption).
  - [`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li).
  - [`<ol>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ol).

Comment: nice answer, i understood the op wanted to keep image inside the view without overflow, playing i did this : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/dyaKowJ (for infos and i might have not well interpreted the question.)

Comment: That's a lot of references

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution to your problem without altering the HTML structure is to get rid of absolute positioning since it breaks your 0-marker out of the layout. This can be replaced by making the *relative_div* a grid container an placing the marker and the image in the same div. Moreover, we need to get rid of the *overflow: hidden*.
A possible solution can be found in [this codepen](https://codepen.io/mledl/pen/WNPyrWy).

The correpsonding code looks like this.

```css
.outermost-container {
  padding: 40px;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.image-centering-div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.relative-div {
  display: grid;
}

.relative-div img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
}

.relative-div div {
    display: flex;
    align-self: flex-end;
    justify-self: flex-end;
    grid-row: 1;
    grid-column: 1;
}

.marker {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outermost-container">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="image-centering-div">
      <div class="relative-div">
        <img src="https://wallpapercave.com/dwp2x/wp4471355.jpg" alt="">
        <div class="marker">O</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-centering-div">
      <div class="relative-div">
        <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1699534956827-a02df22f4e3a?q=80&w=3540&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt="">
        <div class="marker">O</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-centering-div">
      <div class="relative-div">
        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1510505678115-f2a7ae4cfea9?q=80&w=1681&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt="">
        <div class="marker">O</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-centering-div">
      <div class="relative-div">
        <img src="https://plus.unsplash.com/premium_photo-1661852207925-4f1d03556a2e?q=80&w=3540&auto=format&fit=crop&ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=M3wxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8fA%3D%3D" alt="">
        <div class="marker">O</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope this helps you resolving your issue.